# Class conforming to Decodable doesn't require an initializer

Tags: swift, swift4

I'm currenty playing around with `Decodable`, `Encodable` and friends, trying to understand the  "magic" behind it.

One thing that I find unusual is the following:

```
class Person: Decodable {
  var name: String
  var age: Int
}
```

The compiler gladly accepts it. If I had defined it to be a `struct` I'd understand it; the compiler creates implicit initializers for `struct`s.

But **why does this work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler also creates default implementations for types that conform to `Encodable` and `Decodable` as long as all of their properties are types that also conform.

[image]

From the original proposal here: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0166-swift-archival-serialization.md